# Laravel identify collection instance key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I've setup a one to many relationships and I would like to retrieve the many results and display those onto my blade template. I'm currently getting the following error `Property [job_title] does not exist on this collection instance.`

I think this is because I'm trying to get the many results which although there is only one its a collection. My question is how do I know what the key is to loop around to echo my data e.g
`@foreach ($WhatHere? as something)`

Here is my code -

**Relationships**

```
//Client model
public function contact() {
   return $this->hasMany(Contact::class, 'client_id', 'id');
}

//Contct model
public function client() {
    return $this->hasOne(Client::class, 'id', 'client_id');
}
```

**Controller Query**

```
public function show(Client $client, $id)
{
    $client = Client::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();

    return view('clients.single', compact('client'));
}
```

**Blade**

```
{{$client->contact->job_title}}
```

Comment: You can use `Client::findOrFail($id)` instead of what you have, does the same thing but shorter

Comment: Just a note: You could pluralize your 'contact' method to be `contacts()` so it reflects that they are more than one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's one-to-many relationship, you need to iterate over contacts:

```
@foreach ($client->contact as $contact)
    {{ $contact->job_title}}
@endforeach
```

Or you can display only first contact:

```
{{ $client->contact->first()->job_title }}
```

Comment: Ah perfect. make so much sense! I access to the contact in the foreach using the $client as my accessor. Perfect thank you